# Python: How to convert date string into datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

I have a date string - "Fri Jun 05 15:59:14 PDT 2020" How to convert into [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object?

i have tried below format, its not working.

```
'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

Comment: There may be an issue with your timezone abbreviation, I've used ```pytz``` library in the past, it could work for you as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from dateutil import parser

date_string = "Fri Jun 05 15:59:14 PDT 2020"
datetime_obj = parser.parse(date_string)

print(datetime_obj)
```

output:-

```
2020-06-05 15:59:14
```

try using `parse` to
Converts the string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent,

Comment: that ignores `PDT`. see the dupe I linked, you can provide a `tzinfos` mapping to avoid that.

Comment: @FObersteiner yes you're right  without `tzinfo()` ,by default it uses system current time.